# SQL adding decimal resulting in : Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two numbers stored in database as decimal with precision equals to 9. My objective is to add these two numbers and update the value in database.

```
DECLARE @v1 DECIMAL(9, 5), @v2 DECIMAL(9, 5)
SET @v1 = 9503.34000
SET @v2 = 1357.62000
SELECT CAST(@v1 + @v2 AS DECIMAL(9, 5))
```

When i add this in SQL it throws overflow error however on changing it to 10,5 it results in **10860.96000** .

How can i tell SQL to add and return result based on precision i want. I want this sum to return me 9,5 NOT 10,5.

Comment: Since the value of your sum is more than 10'000 - you **cannot** have it be `DECIMAL(9,5)` - this is a decimal number with a total of 9 digits, 5 of which are after the decimal point. That only leaves 4 digits *before* the decimal point, which is **insufficient** to hold your result.

Comment: Thanks marc, i realized that i need to change the design

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It *can't* return `DECIMAL(9,5)`. You have 5 digits in front of the decimal place as 9,503 + 1,357 is greater than 10,000.

If you only want 9 digits in total use `CAST(@v1 +@v2 as DECIMAL(10,4))`. You don't seem to use the 5th decimal place anyway.